Splitting a polyline with multiple features on specific point locations with the function st_split in R
I would like to split a river network with points that locate directly on the river network itself (Snapped them in QGIS). I used the st_split function sufficiently in R, however the function also splits the polyline object of the river network where features change. I would like to stay with the package I am using right now. When this test approach works I will need to split a much bigger river network with around 8000 points.
Mocking data
Some example data is provided in the comment section below.
The code:
#load shapefiles
shape_rivers <- st_read("Flüsse_test.shp")
shape_QBW <- st_read("QBW_test.shp")
shape_Startpunkte <- st_read("Startpunkte_test.shp")

#create id for QBW
QBW_mutate <- shape_QBW%>%
  mutate(id=1:nrow(.))

#Simplify river shapefile
shape_river_simple <- shape_rivers %>%
  st_as_sf %>%
  st_union()

#check
ggplot() +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_minimal() +
  ggspatial::layer_spatial(shape_rivers, aes(color = EIGEN_EZG))+
  ggspatial::layer_spatial(QBW_mutate) +
  scale_color_viridis(direction = -1, name= "upstream area \n(log10[Km^2])") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  ggspatial::annotation_scale(location = "bl", style = "ticks") +
  ggspatial::annotation_north_arrow(location = "br")+
  labs(caption = "Black dots are the position of the dams")

#dams snapped
# Check if dams were snapped properly to the network (all the distances should be zero)
st_distance(QBW_mutate, shape_river_simple) %>% sum
## 0 [m]

#split river network
test_split <- lwgeom::st_split(shape_river_simple, QBW_mutate) %>%
  st_collection_extract(.,"LINESTRING") %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  mutate(length = st_length(.)) %>%
  mutate(segments=1:nrow(.)) %>%
  mutate(type = "QBW")


This is my working result:

River network split at specific points. Red circles indicate a feature change within the river network data. At this feature changes the river network should not be split.
What I already tried:
Dissolve the river network. The river network is still split at the features. Additionally after the split I still need the information form all the features for further analysis so dissolving is not the best option anyway.
My idea:
Maybe I could extract the points where the features change within the river network. In a second step I could filter these points within the st_split function. Is that possible? And how would this work?
Some information on the data:
river shapefile:
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 117 fields
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 355267.4 ymin: 5640683 xmax: 440806.2 ymax: 5724165
Projected CRS: ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N

point shapefile:
Simple feature collection with 25 features and 46 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 376410.1 ymin: 5671794 xmax: 383393.6 ymax: 5684574
Projected CRS: ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N

Interim finding:
@dimfalk helped me to solve a part of my problem (see answer below).
Now i added another row in the results for each segment that resulted from the split and choose a color ramp for those segments. Additionally I tried to join the results with the original river shape files as I need this information for further analysis.
#rbind again
results <- dplyr::bind_rows(results) |>
  dplyr::mutate(segments=1:nrow(results))
results

#set colors
nb.cols <- 29
mycolors <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Set2"))(nb.cols)

#inspect
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = results, aes(col = as.factor(segments)))+
  geom_sf(data = qbw)+
  scale_color_manual(values = mycolors)

#bind split to river network
rivers_joined <- sf::st_join(results, rivers, join = st_is_within_distance, dist = 0.01 )  ###join with original river shapefile

First result

The problem is now that some of the split segments refer to multiple features in the original river shape file. For example: In the original river file Elbe is divided in 3 features so when i join them again there are for the Elbe (only 1 segment in the results) 3 joined features. I will add it to the question above.

Would you please edit your question and provide a minimal, self-contained, and reproducible example? Your chances of receiving an answer increase dramatically if the problem is reproducible, and that is difficult without having your current data.

I provided mocking data for my points, but my polylines have no coordinates. I tried to convert them to points in r, but there are a lot of points now and i think i can not provide such a big table here. Do you have any suggestions?

I don't think you need complex real-world geometries for a proof of concept, so you could keep your example minimal by e.g. contructing rather simplified lines from scratch using sf::st_linestring(). Strangely enough, I can't think of a built-in linestring vector dataset somewhere... But we can get one from {rnaturalearth}, e.g. ne_download(scale = 10, type = "rivers_lake_centerlines", category = "physical") |> dplyr::filter(name = "Mosel"). Finally, if this does not work for you at all, you could also upload your data somewhere to make it accessible.

I created a wetransfer link: https://we.tl/t-EMxriUaOT7
Here you can access the river and point data. Hope that helps.

You can get rid of the transition node by using rivers_simple <- st_union(rivers) |> st_line_merge() , as far as I can judge. But this does not help you with your other river mouths apart from Elbe, e.g. Mehltheuer Bach -> Jahna-3 and Keppritzbach-2 -> Jahna-3. I guess these splits are undesired, too?

And to me, it seems like this is default behaviour for lwgeom::st_split() because when you split rivers_simple by some random point outside your bbox, e.g. c(0, 0), you'll still receive 7 features - and this is the starting point to be modified by inputting the 25 features by qbw_mutate. That's why your result test_split contains 32 features.

I used your suggestion and the splits where the feature changes in Elbe and Keppritzbach are gone. However, the splits where one river of lower order flows into one river of higher order are also undisered. For example where Jahna-3 flows into the Elbe. Any suggestions for this?

Still not 100 % sure if this is what you need. However, what I am sure about that there will be faster and more elegant solutions to this but maybe this can be a starting point for a more sophisticated approach.
As far as I can judge, lwgeom::st_split() also seems to split x by itself using a MULTILINESTRING as input (resulting in undesired splits at river mouths):
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.8.2, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr)
library(lwgeom)
#> Linking to liblwgeom 3.0.0beta1 r16016, GEOS 3.11.2, PROJ 9.3.1
library(ggplot2)

# load data
rivers <- sf::st_read("rivers_mocking.shp")
qbw <- sf::st_read("QBW_mocking.shp")

rivers_simple <- sf::st_union(rivers) |> sf::st_line_merge()
rivers_simple
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> Geometry type: MULTILINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 355267.4 ymin: 5640683 xmax: 440806.2 ymax: 5724165
#> Projected CRS: ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N
#> MULTILINESTRING ((382170.7 5685315, 382169.7 56...

# warm up using a point far outside the bbox of `river_simple`
lwgeom::st_split(rivers_simple, st_sfc(st_point(c(0, 0)))) |> 
  sf::st_collection_extract("LINESTRING") 
#> Geometry set for 7 features 
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 355267.4 ymin: 5640683 xmax: 440806.2 ymax: 5724165
#> Projected CRS: ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N
#> First 5 geometries:
#> LINESTRING (382170.7 5685315, 382169.7 5685315,...
#> LINESTRING (374595.1 5679501, 374596 5679500, 3...
#> LINESTRING (376793.3 5671140, 376793.9 5671141,...
#> LINESTRING (379464.8 5675261, 379465.4 5675260,...
#> LINESTRING (377668.7 5680666, 377669.5 5680666,...

So my idea was to simply iterate over individual streams of your river network (this is probably the part one would want to talk about efficiency, but let's care about the result per se at first), split them into chunks and rbind resulting objects in the end. To make this work, we first need (another brave assumption here) to group and summarize our rivers by OWK_NAME and I assumed that dropping dashes and ids results in the 'real' stream name which can be used for aggregation if the name is not unique, e.g. Elbe-1 and Elbe-2 being merged to Elbe. Initially my intention was to use lapply() for this but somehow I failed implementing this - so here is a basic for loop:
# group and summarise by stream name
rivers_summarised <- rivers |> 
  dplyr::mutate(STREAM = stringr::str_extract(OWK_NAME, pattern = "[A-z]+(?=-[0-9]+)")) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(STREAM = ifelse(is.na(STREAM), OWK_NAME, STREAM)) |> 
  dplyr::group_by(STREAM) |> 
  dplyr::summarise() |> 
  sf::st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") |> 
  sf::st_line_merge()
rivers_summarised
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 355267.4 ymin: 5640683 xmax: 440806.2 ymax: 5724165
#> Projected CRS: ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   STREAM                                                                geometry
#> * <chr>                                                         <LINESTRING [m]>
#> 1 Elbe            (440806.2 5640683, 440805.2 5640684, 440804.3 5640684, 440803…
#> 2 Jahna           (374595.1 5679501, 374596 5679500, 374596.8 5679500, 374597.7…
#> 3 Keppritzbach    (376793.3 5671140, 376793.9 5671141, 376794.4 5671142, 376795…
#> 4 Mehltheuer Bach (379464.8 5675261, 379465.4 5675260, 379466 5675259, 379466.6…

# split individual streams
results <- list()

for (i in 1:dim(rivers_summarised)[1]) {
  
  results[[i]] <- lwgeom::st_split(rivers_summarised[i, ], qbw) |> 
    sf::st_collection_extract("LINESTRING") |> 
    sf::st_as_sf()
}

# rbind again
results <- dplyr::bind_rows(results)
results
#> Simple feature collection with 29 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 355267.4 ymin: 5640683 xmax: 440806.2 ymax: 5724165
#> Projected CRS: ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N
#> # A tibble: 29 × 2
#>    STREAM                                                               geometry
#>  * <chr>                                                        <LINESTRING [m]>
#>  1 Elbe   (440806.2 5640683, 440805.2 5640684, 440804.3 5640684, 440803.3 56406…
#>  2 Jahna  (383028.3 5684574, 383027.6 5684574, 383027 5684575, 383026.4 5684576…
#>  3 Jahna  (374595.1 5679501, 374596 5679500, 374596.8 5679500, 374597.7 5679500…
#>  4 Jahna  (383393.6 5684116, 383394 5684117, 383394.3 5684118, 383394.7 5684119…
#>  5 Jahna  (377908.6 5680807, 377909.5 5680807, 377910.5 5680807, 377911.5 56808…
#>  6 Jahna  (378353.1 5681089, 378353.9 5681090, 378354.6 5681090, 378355.4 56810…
#>  7 Jahna  (376572 5680287, 376572.9 5680287, 376573.9 5680287, 376574.9 5680287…
#>  8 Jahna  (379852.1 5682264, 379853 5682264, 379853.9 5682264, 379854.9 5682264…
#>  9 Jahna  (376410.1 5680342, 376411 5680343, 376411.9 5680343, 376412.8 5680343…
#> 10 Jahna  (376556.7 5680285, 376557.7 5680285, 376558.6 5680286, 376559.5 56802…
#> # ℹ 19 more rows

# inspect
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = results, aes(col = STREAM)) +
  geom_sf(data = qbw)


This is probably not the final result in terms of required attributes but let's focus on geometry first maybe. If some information from original river or qwb is missing, we should be able to solve this making use of sf::st_join().
And before I forget: You should be able to accomplish your snapping via {sf} also, c.f. ?st_snap, so maybe there is no need for pre-processing using QGIS.

Awesome! That is how it should be. Thank you! I tried to join the results with the original river shape file with sf::st_join(). Additonally i added another row called 'segments'. The problem is now that some of the split segments refer to multiple features in the original river shape file. For example: In the original river file Elbe is divided in 3 features so when i join them again there are for the Elbe (only 1 segment in the results) 3 joined features.
I will add it to the question above.

@IchmagNuss: Great, happy to help. I feel like this would qualify for another question because, as you state, there is some additional complexity to be expected and your original quesetion - how to split your river network by points - has been answered, from my point of view. Divide and conquer.
